# Creating/Formatting a .txt file from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export a table from sql and save it as an .txt using powershell. However, when I open my .txt file the data is not in table format

This is the format of my .txt file:

```
Name    :  Billy Bob
Address :  Nowhere Rd
State   :  NA
Number  :  999-999-9999
```

I would like for my .txt to be written in this format:

```
Name, Address, State, Number
Billy Bob, Nowhere Rd, NA, 999-999-9999
```

Or even this format will do, where the space between each column is the tab key

```
Name          Address        State     Number
Billy Bob     Nowhere Rd     NA        999-999-9999
```

Comment: Maybe post your current code?

Answer (score 3):

without your code is not easy help you but if $a is a variable containinng the exported SQL table try this:

```
$a | export-csv "my.txt"
```

Comment: Powershell reads a sql query then output the query into an .txt file

Comment: Here is the code that create the .txt file. The file name is try2.txt <p>$DataSet.tables[0] | Out-File C:\example\try2.txt </p> Thanks

Comment: use export-csv instead out-file for have a file with comma separed values